# Codeigniter something wrong with template and including views

Tags: php, codeigniter

Maybe you can not help me, but maybe you have some ideas where to try to find the problem. I have Template page what looks like this:

dve_kolone.php

```
<?php $this->load->view('frontend/inc/header'); ?>
<?php $this->load->view('frontend/inc/logo'); ?>

<?php if(empty($pretraga_prikaz)) {
    $this->load->view('frontend/inc/pretraga');
}
?>
    <div id="main_content"> 
        <div class="sprite" id="main_content_header"> 
            <div class="kolacici belit"> <?php if(!empty($kolacici)) { echo $kolacici;}?> </div>
            <div id="main_brojac_gore" class="f20 bold belit ml200"   style="position:relative;"><h1><?php if(!empty($naslov)) { echo $naslov;}?>

            </h1><?php if(!empty($oglas_izmene)) { echo $oglas_izmene;} ?></div>    


        </div>
        <div id="mainov" class="dve_kolone">        
        <div id="main_levo">
            <?php 
            if(!empty($levo)) {
                $this->load->view($levo);
            } else {
                $this->load->view('frontend/inc/levo_standard');
            } ?>
        </div>
        <div id="main_sredina_full" class="<?if(!empty($klasa)){ echo $klasa;}?>">

<?php 
if(!empty($partial)) {
    $this->load->view($partial);
} else {
    redirect(base_url());
} ?>
<br class="cl"/>
</div>
<br class="cl"/>
</div>
</div>

<?php $this->load->view('frontend/inc/footer'); ?>
```

In controller I am sending two views and the title to this. In view is the simple word:

```
function nesto()
{
    $data['naslov'] = 'Kursna lista';
    $data['partial'] = 'proba';
    $this->load->view('frontend/dve_kolone', $data);
}
```

In live its look slike this: http://www.svastara.rs/anketa/nesto

And now I will show you another page in live where it looks perfect: http://www.svastara.rs/kursna_lista/eur

So my problem is you will see that there is missing at first link one menu in footer with red line.
I do not understand why, because on other pages where is used this template, on lot of times there is no css used just simple stuff included. And now I put a simple stuff, but the page is not fitting height to page or to text, it is too much big. And I do not made changes on any CSS:S

I hope you have some ideas

FOOTER non working part:

```
<div id="footer" class="sprite">
    <div class="footer_nav fl">
        <ul class="navig">

            <li><a href="<?=base_url()?>info/predaja_oglasa">PREDAJA OGLASA</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?=base_url()?>info/reklamiranje">REKLAMIRANJE</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?=base_url()?>horoskop">HOROSKOP</a></li>
            <li class="nbr"><a href="info/kontakt">KONTAKT</a></li>
            <ul>
    </div>
    <div id="footer_social">

        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/"><img src="<?=slika()?>" class="sprite youtube fl hop"/></a>
        <a href="http://www.twitter.com/v_svastara"><img src="<?=slika()?>" class="sprite twitter fl hop"/></a>
        <a href="http://facebook.com/Vojvodjanska.Svastara"><img src="<?=slika()?>" class="sprite facebook fl hop"/></a>
    </div>

    <br class="cl"/>
```

Comment: This might be because you have not separated your design properly.Try closing a div just about your <?php $this->load->view('frontend/inc/footer'); ?>  or may be removing a div.

Comment: But that first file works, in every other variation. that is like a template. just on this new http://www.svastara.rs/anketa/nesto link do not work. 
The problem is that someone other made a site.

Comment: It seems there is some issue with the url. As the urls are relative they are causing trouble.Can you show me the codeigniter  code of your footer[Just the links code which are not working].

Comment: Look the FOOTER part in question.

Comment: Are all the "missing" links ones you've used with short tag, e.g. `<?` instead of `<?php`? If so, then you've got to turn on `short_open_tag` in your `php.ini`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace    `<li class="nbr"><a href="info/kontakt">KONTAKT</a></li>`

with `<li class="nbr"><a href="<?=base_url()?>info/kontakt">KONTAKT</a></li>`

in your footer code.